# How does docker0 bridge work internally inside the host?

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

I am trying to understand how the bridged docker0 interface works.

- When docker daemon starts up, it creates a bridged device docker0;
- When a container starts up, it creates a interface vthn and bind to docker0

say we issue a ping command from inside the container to a external host

```
[root@f505f022eb5b app]# ping 130.49.40.130
PING 130.49.40.130 (130.49.40.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 130.49.40.130: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=11.9 ms
```

so apprently my host eth0 is receiving this ping back, but how does this package get forwarded to the container? There are serveral questions to ask

- eth0 and docker0 are not bridged, how come docker0 get the packets from eth0?
- even if docker0 got the packets, how it works internally sending packets to vth0? does it internally maintains some Maps so it can convert packets to between different mac address?
- how is iptables related here?

Cheers.

Comment: http://woosley.github.io/2017/07/25/understand-docker-iptables-rules.html

Answer (score 2):

Docker is not doing anything specifically magical here and your question is not really docker dependant/related.

`docker0` is just a network bridge. As soon as this bridge is created (upon starting the docker service) you can assume that a new machine (in this case in a VM/docker form) has joined the your network.

When pinging the docker container from host or vice versa you are basically pinging another machine inside your network.

Regarding docker, unless you have created a new network interface (which I doubt so since you are pinging `eth0`) you are basically pinging yourself.

If you run the container as:

`docker run -i -t --rm -p 10.0.0.99:80:8080 ubuntu:16.04`

You are telling docker to create a NAT rule in iptables to forward any packets going to `10.0.0.99:80` to your docker container on port `8080`.

When you run the container as:

`docker run -i -t --rm -p --net=host ubuntu:16.04`

Then you are saying the docker container should have the same network stack as the host so all the packets going to host will also arrive to your docker container via the `docker0` bridge.

Comment: yeah, my question is not really that docker. I am still trying to find out what happened when a docker container is ping a external host. In side the container, if a packet want to reach out and return back, how it pass the host's interface and converted to inside the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, how does a container ping an external host, this is also achieved via NAT.

If you list your Iptables / NAT rules using: `sudo iptables -t nat -L`

You will likely see, something similar to the below (docker subnet may be different)

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
```

This is basically saying NAT any outgoing packets originating from the docker subnet. So the outgoing packets will appear to originate from the docker host machine. When the ping packets return, the NAT table will be used to determine that a docker host actually made the request, and the packet gets forwarded to the docker veth.